# How to show styles and computed at the same time?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have searched through a few questions but I already know that I have to expand my dev tools and dock to the right but it doesn't work.

Some time ago it used to work just fine, then it stopped and now I can only see styles.
see: [image]

And this is how it was before:
[image: devt]

What can I do? My screen is big enough.

Comment: This is the new intended behavior in devtools, see https://crbug.com/1073899. They will add a switch to show both panels in the future. So, you will suffer until then or use a separate older portable Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to @wOxxOm it is a new behavior in devtools and it will come back in the future as switch.